# How to insert a record from one table to another, amount of columns differ

Tags: c#, sql

I have 2 tables, Table1 & Table2

I would like to insert a record from Table1 into Table 2 and then remove that record from Table1 (I am basically moving that record)

I am trying the following:

```
INSERT INTO Table2 SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE cid =" + txt_cid
DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE cid =" + txt_cid
```

However Table2 has few more columns than Table1 and is not allowing me to insert into it. I have 80+ columns in each table so individually entering those columns into the query is a headache.

Is there a way I could do this faster?

Comment: Take some pills for the headache and write the columns your table2 accepts.

Comment: Don't use `*` and specify the columns you want both in the `INSERT` and `SELECT` clause. The server can't guess which columns you want to use.

Comment: lol @Steve is there really no other way to do it?

Comment: You could make a loop, make there your insert statements and fill the missing values of the missing columns with NULL or something.

Comment: @K.Isaac how can the server *guess* what you want, especially when the columns don't match?

Comment: As a side note: If you open SSMS and right click on the table you could use the menu SCRIPT AS.... (SELECT or INSERT) and you get your columns list ready to copy and paste

Comment: @K.Isaac even easier - select the query and hit `Ctrl+Q`. This will open the query designer which will replace the wildcards with column names

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Please elaborate on you last comment, I got abit confused there

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to have a headache.
Specify the columns and make sure that input and output data types match.